# How to give a dynamic name to each textbox while running Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
        <p> March 2014 invoice details(current):
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
        <label>
        <input name="food" type="text" id="food" />
        </label>

        <div id="div"></div>
        <p><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="generateRow()"/></p>
        <p>
        <label>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
        </label>
        </p>
        </form>
        </p>
```

This is my HTML code

Belox is my Javascript functino

```
<script>
var i;
i=0;

function generateRow() 
{
  i++;

var d=document.getElementById("div");
d.name="food";
d.innerHTML+="<p><input type='text' name='xyz ' + i /></p>";
}
```

The above code names all the dynamically created inputbox with the name "xyz"

I want to dynamically name my each input box as "xyz1" ,"xyz2"...

Comment: `d.innerHTML+="<p><input type='text' name='xyz"+i+"' /></p>";`

Comment: Thanks man.! u are a savior.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
d.innerHTML+="<p><input type='text' name='xyz" + i + "' /></p>";
```

instead of

```
d.innerHTML+="<p><input type='text' name='xyz ' + i /></p>";
```

Comment: could you please look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65422388/how-to-name-numerous-dynamic-input-fields-for-post-method-django)